# Focus an input after clicking on a button

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to learn React by making a Todo list (original I know). There a lot of concepts I haven't learnt yet (I'm still using class components) but I was wondering is there a recommended way to focus the input that appears when the edit button is pushed?

I tried using createRef but it still seems not to work. I'm wondering I the input should be a separate component that focuses onMount?

Any direction would be appreciated:

```
export class Item extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.editInput = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
        editView: false
    }
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    this.toggleView = this.toggleView.bind(this);
    this.editMode = this.editMode.bind(this);
}
handleRemove(e){
    this.props.remove(this.props.detail);
}

toggleView(){
    this.setState(prevState => (
        {editView: !prevState.editView }
        ))
}

editMode(){
    this.toggleView();
    
    this.editInput.current.focus();
}

render() {

    const itemView = !this.state.editView ?<div className="item">{this.props.detail}</div> : <input ref={this.editInput} className="edit-item-input" placeholder={this.props.detail + "..."}></input> ;
    return (
        <div className="item-container">
            {itemView}
            <div className="buttons">
                <button onClick={this.editMode} className="button button-edit">Edit</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleRemove} className="button button-delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could add the React `autoFocus` property, on the `input` element, and it should work as you want.